# Where is ant-contrib.jar?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

The [ant-contrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/) project on sourceforge seems to be in disarray.

The [downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/) page says the latest version is cpptasks-1.0b5.zip but [that file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/cpptasks-1.0-beta5/cpptasks-1.0b5.zip/download) does not contain `ant-contrib-*.jar`, or for that matter any other jar. Are binaries no longer available?

This cpptasks is from 2008, the latest available ant-contrib is `1.0b3`, from 2006.

Is this project no longer actively developed? I guess I can work with the 2006 version, but just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the ant-contrib binaries from Maven Central:

- [ant-contrib](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22ant-contrib%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ant-contrib%22)

I don't know anything about the project's health, but I would recommend using an embedded script for complex logic outside of normal ANT. For example [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was able to find `ant-contrib` on sourceforge as well but just wondering about the project. As you can imagine, it is not always practical to modify existing setup so for now I am stuck with ant-contrib but I can use the more sophisticated embedded script approach in future, which too it seems requires an external jar but is lot more expressive